# 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable error when using custom context processors

Tags: django

I am using a custom context processor in Django. But when the user is logged in it works file but when I try to login the user it throws 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Here is the error:

```
 TypeError at /
'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 Django Version:    3.1
 Exception Type:    TypeError
 Exception Value:   'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

And the context_processers file looks like

```
def noti_count(request):
  count1 = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user, seen=False)
  count2 = Notification_general.objects.filter(seen=False)
  return {"count1": count1, 'count2':count2,}
```

And the Context Processors Looks like

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'home.context_processors.noti_count',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
   },
 },
]
```

Please help me out the code works fine for logged in user but when they they try to go to login page after the logout It throws me 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
def noti_count(request):
  if request.user:
      count1 = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user, seen=False)
      ....
```

What do you want to count?